# How can I calculate if the difference between two word frequencies in one corpus is significant?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, corpus-linguistics

I want to study orthographical variants, for example:

Can *firefighter*, *fire-fighter* and *fire fighter* be considered orthographical variants (the difference in frequency in a corpus is not statistically/practically significant), or should one or more of these orthographical forms be considered "wrong"/"irregular" (the difference in frequency is statistically/practically significant)?

In a corpus of 926,766,504 words, I get the following frequency counts (on lemmas):

- *firefighter* = 3,349
- *fire-fighter* = 336
- *fire fighter* = 1,338

What statistical measure(s) can I use to say, for example, that there is not a large enough difference between *firefighter* and *fire fighter* to consider the latter "irregular", but that the difference between *firefighter* and *fire-fighter* is significant?

**One specific sub-question**:

If I work with probabilities (e.g. firefighter = 0,667; fire-fighter = 0,067; fire fighter = 0,266), is there a way to measure if the difference is significant? (Beyond just stating the obvious that the one occurs with a higher probability than the other.)

Comment: A corpus cannot tell you if an orthographic variant is correct or not.  Typically a panel of native speakers is used to rate correctness.

Comment: I used "wrong" specifically between inverted commas, because that is not the real issue here. It is more about whether a certain form occurs so frequently that it could be considered a viable spelling alternative. Such statistical information would typically inform a panel of experts, as you mentioned.

Comment: What is the difference between "correct" and "viable spelling alternative?"  I do not think there is one.  I disagree with you about the "real issue."  The real issue is that a corpus does not contain correctness information.

Answer (score 1):

This might answer your question: [Statistical significance between letter frequencies in different corpora](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234157/statistical-significance-between-letter-frequencies-in-different-corpora?rq=1)

You can use a chi square test of independence.

Comment: As I understand it, this is specifically not an option, because I draw frequencies from the same corpus. Hence, the assumption of independence is violated. Please correct me if I'm wrong. (I'm a statistics virgin!)